# How could I create a button that creates and download an excel in FLutter Web

Tags: excel, flutter, dart, web-applications

[image]

This is what I found, but it still doesn't work to add more data at once as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Do not add pictures of the code. Add code as formatted text in the question. Have a look at these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: declare newk as a String data type  `String? newk;`  then `newk = 'A$k';`